# Vue3 vue-i18n Lazy loading

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I would like to implement lazy loading for individual languages in my APP, however I don't really understand the example.
Example: https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/lazy.html

i18n.js

```
import { nextTick } from 'vue'
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

export const SUPPORT_LOCALES = ['de', 'en']

export function setupI18n(options = { locale: 'de' }) {
  const i18n = createI18n(options)
  setI18nLanguage(i18n, options.locale)
  return i18n
}

export function setI18nLanguage(i18n, locale) {
  if (i18n.mode === 'legacy') {
    i18n.global.locale = locale
  } else {
    i18n.global.locale.value = locale
  }
  document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('lang', locale)
}

export async function loadLocaleMessages(i18n, locale) {
  // load locale messages with dynamic import
  const messages = await import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "locale-[request]" */ `./locales    /${locale}.json`
  )

  // set locale and locale message
  i18n.global.setLocaleMessage(locale, messages.default)

  return nextTick()
}
```

My folder structure looks quite similar.
I don't use the composition API at this point.

Instead of loading the languages via vue-router I would like to define a default language which can be changed in the user settings.

Where and how do I have to load the function "loadLocaleMessages()" now?

Currently I load the configuration in my main.js like this so that I have "$t" available in the template:

```
import { setupI18n } from "@/plugins/i18n";
...
app.use(setupI18n());
...
```

The i18n.js looks like in the example only that my path for the languages is different.

Also I would like to know how I have to include everything so that I have e.g. "$t" also available in other (not components)?
E.g. in the routes.js or in the store (vuex)

EDIT:
middlewares.js - beforeEachHook

```
import { i18n } from "@/plugins/i18n"
const { t } = i18n.global

/**
 * Translate/set page title
 */
export function setPageTitleMiddleware (to, from, next) {
    const pageTitle = to.matched.find(item => item.meta.title)

    if (to.meta && to.meta.title)
        window.document.title = process.env.VUE_APP_DOMAIN_TITLE + ' | ' + t(to.meta.title)
    else if
        (pageTitle && pageTitle.meta) window.document.title = process.env.VUE_APP_DOMAIN_TITLE + ' | ' + t(pageTitle.meta.title)

    next()
}
```

Comment: Please, post relevant code in the question, it should be understandable without navigating to external links that may change. " how I have to include everything so that I have e.g" - this is what JS imports are for. Import `t` where it's used

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added the code.
I know how imports work - that's not the problem. $t should be globally available if I understood the doc correctly - I'm concerned about how/where I have to call "loadLocaleMessages()" and if I then have to do in e.g. main.js "import { setupI18n } from "@/plugins/i18n";" or if that's already wrong.

Comment: You would call loadLocaleMessages when the user chooses which language they want to display. `$t` should not really be necessary outside of components. It is only meant to help display the text. Use a primary language for routes and store and translate in components only. (i.e. rather than work with the translated text, work with the translation keys instead).

Comment: But how do I call "loadLocaleMessages(i18n, locale)" if I don't have a variable "i18n"?
I would do this normally with "import { i18n } from '@/plugins/i18n'" which I don't have anymore according to the doc - I have a function here and would have to import the following if I'm right: "import { setupI18n } from '@/plugins/i18n'", right?

An example for my usage of $t would be to set the pagetitle via router-middleware: window.document.title = process.env.VUE_APP_DOMAIN_TITLE + ' | ' + t(`general.${pageTitle.meta.title}`)

Comment: No, it shouldn't be globally available. $t is made available in component templates because it would be tedious to import it in each component and expose it on component instance. This isn't so with i18n.t. You need to export somewhere `const i18n = setupI18n(..)`  (could be in i18n.js too) and import it where it's used. You can destructure it to `t` to make this less verbose. "Where and how do I have to load the function " - somewhere in root component or router hook? The idea is that you need to complete it before messages are shown, there could be loading indicator when it's loading

Answer (score 0):

To be able to get i18n translation from anywhere in your application (vue3 in my case) :

```js
import i18n from "@/i18n";

i18n.global.t("your_key")
```